# Effective use of vmlaq_s16

Tags: arm, simd, neon

When using the **vmlaq_s16** intrinsic/**VMLA.I16** instruction, the result takes the form of a set of 8 *16-bit* integers. The multiplies inside the instructions however require the results to be stored in *32-bit* integers to protect from overflow.

On Intel processors with SSE2, _mm_madd_epi16 preserves the length of the instruction (8 16-bit integers into 4 32-bit results) by multiplying and adding pairs of consecutive elements of the vectors, i.e.

```
r0 := (a0 * b0) + (a1 * b1)
r1 := (a2 * b2) + (a3 * b3)
r2 := (a4 * b4) + (a5 * b5)
r3 := (a6 * b6) + (a7 * b7)
```

Where r0,r1,r2,r3 are all 32-bit, and a0-a7, b0-b7 are all 16-bit elements.

Is there a trick that I'm missing with the vmlaq_s16 instruction that would allow me to still be able to process 8 16-bit elements at once and have results that don't overflow? Or is it the fact that this instruction is just provided for operands that are inherently in the 4-bit range (highly doubtful)?

Thanks!

**EDIT**: So I just thought about the fact that if vmlaq_s16 sets the overflow register flag(s?) for each of the elements in the result, then it's easy to count the overflows and recover the result.

**EDIT 2**: For everyone's reference, here's how to load 8 elements and pipeline two long multiply-adds on a 128bit register with intrinsics (proof of concept code that compiles with VS2012 for the ARM target):

```
signed short vector1[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8};
signed short vector2[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8};

int16x8_t v1; // = vdupq_n_s16(0);
int16x8_t v2; // = vdupq_n_s16(0);

v1 = vld1q_s16(vector1);
v2 = vld1q_s16(vector2);

int32x4_t sum = vdupq_n_s16(0);
sum = vmlal_s16(sum, v1.s.low64, v2.s.low64);
sum = vmlal_s16(sum, v1.s.high64, v2.s.high64);

printf("sum: %d\n", sum.n128_i32[0]);
```

Comment: Sadly, NEON has no concept of a flags register - the closest you get is the untrapped floating-point exception status bits, which are no help at all here :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These aren't directly equivalent operations - `VMLA` multiples two vectors then adds the result elementwise to *a 3rd vector*, unlike the self-contained half-elementwise-half-horizontal craziness of Intel's `PMADDWD`. Since that 3rd vector is a regular operand it has to exist in a register, thus there's no room for a 256-bit accumulator.

If you don't want to risk overflow by using `VMLA` to do 8x16 * 8x16 + 8x16, the alternative is to use `VMLAL` to do 4x16 * 4x16 + 4x32. The obvious suggestion would be to pipeline pairs of instructions to process 8x16 vectors into two 4x32 accumulators then add them together at the end, but I'll admit I'm not too familiar with intrinsics so I don't know how difficult they would make that (compared to assembly where you can exploit the fact that "64-bit vectors" and "128-bit vectors" are simply interchangable views of the same register file).

Comment: Thanks. That's what I'm doing currently - vmlal_s16, and it bugs me that it's just using half the "available" bandwidth.

So the merit of the obvious suggestion of pipelining pairs of instructions is that it saves another load, correct? That is, instead of doing two 8-byte loads I'd be doing one 16-byte load at the beginning of the block, which would save one trip to the memory and cache.

Comment: Indeed - if the data's already in registers, each extra `VMLAL` only costs 1 more cycle (on top of the initial ~5-10 cycle result latency), and I _believe_ some cores will actually let you pipeline multiple instructions using the same accumulator register without any additional penalty. As I understand NEON, careful preloading and keeping the L1 full is more important than anything else - data processing "bandwidth" is almost free compared to the load/store bottleneck.

Comment: This was a great idea, but it only speeded up my code by about 10%. I'll look into the assembly more to see if I can interleave memory loads with the vmlal instructions better than the MSVS ARM compiler.